# Python: add a book with user input

Tags: python

I’m trying to add a book to an inventory list, based on user input and get a "str not callable" error?

```
#Add a book, based on user input 
def add_book():
    # purpose: add a book
    print()
    print("Adding a New Book..")
    print()
        
    title = input("Title> ")
    author = input("Author> ")
    isbn = input("ISBN> ")
    callnumber = input("CallNumber> ")
    stock = input("Stock> ")
    loaned = input("Loaned> ")        
    inventory.append = (title, author, isbn, callnumber, stock, loaned)
```

I'm not sure how else to ask for input to append the new book to existing ist of books?

Comment: What's `inventory`? A list? If so, it should be `inventory.append((title, author,...))`, assuming you want to append each book as a tuple.

Comment: Also, `inventory` should be an argument of `add_book()`.

Comment: thanks for the feedback....I've corrected those, but still get a 'Type Error'.... 'str object is not callable' for 'title = input("Title > ") and  'add_book(inventory)' later on

Comment: It works for me using my previous suggestion and adding a `return inventory`. And your code produces `'str' object has no attribute 'append'`. Please add the full error stack and the definition of `inventory`. In fact, it would be better to have a complete [mre].

Answer (score 0):

That is not the correct syntax to append to a `list`.

Assuming inventory is a `list` type, the `append()` method takes a single argument and appends it to the list.

```
inventory.append(title)
```

You will need to do this for each element you wish to append, or append them as a tuple of items

```
inventory.append((title, author, isbn, callnumber, stock, loaned))
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback....I've made some corrections, but still get a 'Type Error'.... 'str object is not callable' for 'title = input("Title > ") and 'add_book(inventory)' later on

Comment: do you have a global variable you named 'input' that you assigned a string value to? my guess is you did, which means the python input method is now a string variable in your code, which is why you would get a 'str object is not callable' error

Answer (score 0):

You will first want to adjust your function to allow for a inventory "list" to be passed to it, like so:

```
def add_book(inventory):
```

From here you will be able to append a "tuple" with values separated by commas , like so:

```
inventory.append((title, author, isbn, callnumber, stock, loaned))
```

Be careful to make sure to have the tuple elements stored in their own parentheses, in addition to the ones from the append method.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't define the **inventory**.
You have to devine above in your code then variable **inventory** the use it.